# Scikit Learn) is n_jobs=-1 still faster than n_jobs= c when we are running multiple Random Forest in Paralllel?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, parallel-processing, cpu

I am currently running 8 Random Forest models(each with grid search) on 8 different datasets for 1000 times. To save time, I opened up 8 different terminals and am running each models in parallel. Now, my question is

Is it faster to train each random forest models with the argument `n_jobs` ==-1 or is it better to assign number of cores such as `n_jobs=3`? I have 26 cores available. Thus I may be able to assign at most 3 cores to each model.

Looking at the cpu usage with `htop`, I can see that running with `n_jobs=-1` already makes full use of all cpus. Would it be possible that setting the `n_jobs=-1` actually results in bottleneck when distributing the data to each core?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest in my opinion would be to use `n_jobs=-1` in all 8 terminals and your computer will internally allocate as needed the necessary CPU resources to each worker.